# Unable to get longitude and latitude in ios8 by GPS

Tags: ios, ios8, gps, location, core-location

I am using iOS8 and using the following code for getting longitude and latitude by GPS:

```
-(void)CurrentLocationIdentifier
{
    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0 &&
    [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse)
    //[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways)
    {
    // Will open an confirm dialog to get user's approval
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    //[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    } else {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; //Will update location immediately
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"lat%f - lon%f", location.coordinate.latitude,   location.coordinate.longitude);
 }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    switch (status) {
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: {
        NSLog(@"User still thinking..");
    }
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied: {
        NSLog(@"User hates you");
    } break;
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways: {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; //Will update location immediately
    } break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

After running this code I am getting the output at log is : User still thinking. Can anyone help me with this I am new to iOS and CoreLocation.Framework ?
Please help me in finding the Error and how can I solve that.

Comment: Are you checking this on simulator or real device?

Comment: @TapasPal I am checking it on simulator and  I have done setup like debug>Simulate Location>option and for simulator debug>location>Apple. I followed this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this string in InfoPlist.strings files

```
1) NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

2) NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Try this code

```
locationManagerApp=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManagerApp.delegate = self;
    locationManagerApp.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManagerApp.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {        
           [locationManagerApp requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [locationManagerApp startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location1 = [locationManagerApp location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location1 coordinate];
    self.latValue= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    self.longValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"Latitude  = %@", self.latValue);
    NSLog(@"Longitude = %@", self.longValue);
```

And run project in device.

Comment: First of all sorry for late reply but I want to run it in simulator where I have done setup like debug>Simulate Location>option and for simulator debug>location>Apple. Can you suggest anything regarding this?

Comment: Thank you for the help and suggestion. I added the string in infoPlist.strings file and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 you need to do two extra things to get location working: Add a key to your Info.plist and request authorization from the location manager asking it to start. There are two Info.plist keys for the new location authorization. One or both of these keys is required. If neither of the keys are there, you can call startUpdatingLocation but the location manager won’t actually start. It won’t send a failure message to the delegate either (since it never started, it can’t fail). It will also fail if you add one or both of the keys but forget to explicitly request authorization.

So the first thing you need to do is to add one or both of the following keys to your Info.plist file:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Both of these keys take a string which is a description of why you need location services. You can enter a string like “Location is required to find out where you are” which, as in iOS 7, can be localized in the InfoPlist.strings file.